# Qooxdoo native + desktop

Tags: qooxdoo

Доброго времени суток. Возникла задача:
1. Есть Javascript SDK, который написан на qooxdoo native
2. Есть desktop Qooxdoo сайт.

Задача в том, чтобы подключить native библиотеку к desktop сайту.
При попытке подключения сайт начинает неимоверно глючить и возникают непонятного рода ошибки. Никто не сталкивался ?

Answer (score 1):

Qooxdoo - довольно редкая в России тема (к сожалению, мне фреймворк очень нравится), я думаю лучше спросить на англоязычном ресурсе. Используй тег qooxdoo на stackoverflow.com, разработчики библиотеки нередко сами отвечают.